# Zeroes of the Alexander polynomial for achiral knots

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, cv.complex-variables, knot-theory

Are there some known properties about the position (on the complex plane) of roots of the Alexander polynomial of achiral knots? They are shown as blue points in the following picture of roots for knots up to 16 crossings. Specifically what about those sitting in the middle of the holes around chiral ones.

[image]

Added the zoom-out picture: Zeros (in the half unit disc) of the Alexander polynomial for knots up to 16 crossings (red - chiral,alternating; green - chiral,nonalternating; blue - achiral) blue on top of red on top of green

[image]

Edit: A fragment of the roots for the **positive amphichiral** knots (red dots):

[image]

------------------- Edit:

In the picture below we indicate (by orange dots) the roots (of multiplicity more than 1) of Alexander polynomials of prime knots up to 15 crossings (313.230 knots, regardless of their chirality). The number shows the maximal multiplicity among all polynomials.

As suggested by this picture, the holes and their centers have much to do with the multiplicity of roots after all. As in the suggested paper by Hartley, for positive amphicheiral knots, the roots are more frequently have higher (than one) multiplicity because they "potentially" factors through the other polynomials (at least to the second power).

[image]

The isolated roots in the interior are from Alexander polynomials like: $(t^4-3t^3+5t^2-3t+1)^2$, $(t^6-2t^5+4t^4-5t^3+4t^2-2t+1)^2$, $(t^6-5t^5+12t^4-15t^3+12t^2-5t+1)^2$, $(t^4-5t^3+9t^2-5t+1)^2$, $(2t^4-6t^3+9t^2-6t+2)^2$, $(2t^4-7t^3+11t^2-7t+2)^2$, $(t^6-3t^5+5t^4-5t^3+5t^2-3t+1)^2$ ... so they are squares of Alexander polynomials for some knots.

Comment: Could you give us a sense of scale -- where is the unit circle in your picture?  I'm assuming horizontal is the direction of the real axis. Also, what are the other colours?  I see red and green, other than blue.

Comment: Another question: do the gaps around isolated blue dots get (significantly) smaller as you add more knots?

Comment: I have added the zoom-out picture

Comment: The gaps are gradually filled in and in some sort of "spiral galaxy" way

Comment: Thanks,  that's a nice image.  Do you know how the picture changes if you plot the roots of all symmetric polynomials w/integer coefficients and $p(1)=1$? i.e. restrict to the simplest class of polynomials that contains the Alexander polynomials?   This should be significantly simpler work than what you have already done.

Comment: What is the rule you use for colour intensity -- if a root occurs more often do you make the colour relatively dark?  Also, do you have a vector graphic plot available?   I imagine some of your "repeat roots" are round-off issues regarding the plot resolution, and others are genuine repeated roots.  Do you distinguish a root being repeated for an individual knot, vs. it being repeated in a large collection of knots?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, the "curious position" is the inference that it appears there is a clustering phenomena -- as the complexity of the knots increase, their Alexander polynomial roots appear to cluster around the achiral roots of relatively low complexity?  i.e. this is something that looks a little like Thurston's hyperbolic filling theorem.

Comment: For the achiral points, have you checked to see if there is anything interesting that distinguishes the strong achiral points (of various types) from the weak achiral points?  If there is anything interesting going on with that, it might point you in a direction.

Comment: Are you aware of the restrictions on the Alexander polynomials of achiral knots?  https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01420117 See also http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/friedl/papers/determinant-of-amphichiral-knots-june-19-2017.pdf

These criteria indicate that it might be helpful to further distinguish the Alexander polynomials of - and + achiral knots in your plots. However, I don't think necessary and sufficient conditions have been obtained.

Comment: @IanAgol: I wasn't aware of the Friedl paper, but the Hartley paper is just for strongly achiral knots.  I haven't thought much about the consequences of the Friedl paper -- the restrictions seem unlikely to say too much about the locations of the roots.

Comment: @RyanBudney Look at theorem 3.1 in the paper, he doesn’t assume strong amphichirality.

Comment: @IanAgol: Thanks Ian, I was unaware of this theorem.  I generally use Kawauchi's survey book as my guide for this kind of material.  I was thrown-off since Kawauchi's survey is aware of this paper but does not state the theorem of Hartley's.  It does however state a weaker theorem of Kawauchi's from 1979 in great detail. That's curious.

Comment: @RyanBudney seems like a characterization is still lacking, a bit surprising to me.

Comment: Do you know what distinguishes the isolated-looking +achiral knots from the ones that appear to lack this isolated condition?    One possibility would be the strong/weak achiral condition as those likely have different alexander polynomial constraints.

Comment: The ones, not "isolated" turn out to be single roots (without multiplicity), see updated post.

Comment: Presumably these polynomial factors reflect various invariant submodules of the Alexander module, coming from the mirror symmetry.   So what you are seeing must be a reflection of the difficulty of producing these invariant submodules via other low-crossing knot types.     I think a next step would be to investigate the Alexander modules of some of these knots -- could you tell us the names of some of these knots?  For example, what is the knot that is isolated near the centre of your 3rd figure?

Comment: I don't have full names right now, but the DTCode for the knot is [4, 12, -22, -16, -30, -20, 2, -24, 28, -8, -32, -14, -6, 18, 26, -10]

Comment: Thanks.  At present none of the software I rely on for these types of computations is running -- it appears that, between operating-system drift and source-code drift, my software does not compile any more.   I'll see what I can do, but it might take a while.

Comment: I suppose your Alexander polynomial computation says a little more.  These Alexander polynomials are the squares of Alexander polynomials of knots that are "difficult to approximate" by knots with low crossing numbers.

Comment: Recently a characterization of the Alexander polynomials of negative amphichiral knots. https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.03598 This might give some insight into this question.

Answer (score 5):

This is an extended comment, and a response to one of my earlier comments.

The image below depicts the roots of all integer-coefficient Laurent polynomials

$$p(t) = \sum_i a_i t^i$$

that satisfy $p(t^{-1}) = p(t)$, $p(1)=1$ that are of degree at most 6 with coefficients at most 6.  i.e. the sum is over $i=-6 \cdots 6$ and the coefficients $a_i \in \{-6, \cdots, 6\}$.  These latter limitations were to help make the computation reasonably-long.

As in your figure, I only show the roots inside the unit disc with non-negative imaginary part.

[image]

I think the main difference between your image and this one must come down to the manner in which the polynomials are generated.

I believe you are getting Alexander polynomials of much higher degree, but also your coefficients are not uniformly distributed like in the way I generate the polynomials.

So I think your plot is very much a reflection of the "shape" of Alexander polynomials, parametrized by the crossing number.  As you have observed, it appears certain regions in the space of possible Alexander polynomials are more rapidly filled-in by the amphichiral knots.

Perhaps there is a construction that can produce low-crossing amphichiral knots that can also produce a sequence of "approximating" chiral knots, where "approximating" is in terms of roots of the Alexander polynomial.

If you choose the polynomials to be at most degree 26, with coefficients between -2 and 2, uniformly and randomly you get something even further from your plot.

[image]

I tried a less even-handed search through Alexander polynomials, biased towards polynomials that are weakly alternating, like the typical polynomials one sees in knot tables.  Interestingly (maybe only to me), the answer appears to be even further from what you are getting.  Clearly the phenomena I see in the tables isn't enough to characterize what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Your first picture somehow reminds me of an electromagnetic field experiments with iron filings.

Comment: Some of that presumably is Moire Effect -- the cartesian grid coming from how I generate the polynomials vs. the cartesian grid of pixels on the screen.  This is me repeating a comment of Jon Hillman, who has read the thread.

Comment: @RyanBudney Just a heads up: it’s moiré, not Moiré. It’s not a name.

Comment: All typos belong to me, and do not reflect on Jon Hillman.

Comment: I just want to say that these are beautiful and fascinating images, thank you for making them!

Answer (score 2):

As you point out in the modified question, positive achiral knots  have Alexander polynomials that tend to factor by Hartley’s result. So the roots will be roots of smaller degree polynomials.

When you plot roots of polynomials with relatively small coefficients (as in Ryan Budney’s answer), the roots of higher degree polynomials tend to avoid the roots of smaller degree polynomials. [Dan Christensen plotted](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week285.html) roots of polynomials with coefficients in $[-4,4]$, colored by the polynomial degree, where one sees this phenomenon: roots of lower degree polynomials tend to be isolated.

[image: Dan Christensen polynomials with coefficients bounded by 4]

This seems to explain your picture heuristically: the roots of Alexander polynomials of achiral knots tend to be isolated because they are the roots of lower degree polynomials.